# How to find interesting questions without any idea

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tag-watching, related-questions

When we read any question it shows the related questions in the right side.

How do I find the related questions if I don't have any idea/question to search?

We know every question is related to other questions in some way. I think it is good to show that relation/starting links, when we click a particular tag.

I know the popular questions are shown in the wiki of a particular tag, however I guess if we use the relation behind each question we can automate the process and thereby increase the reach-ability to popular/interesting questions.

**Edit-1:**

I assume that **every question** has an **origin**, that is what I mean in the relation/starting links.

If we group questions based on the origin, it will be more easier to find interesting questions.

Currently the questions are related using tags, however these tags show only the topics related to the current question and not the origin of the question.

For example take this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator), it shows that this question is linked only with 'Java' tag, however it doesn't have any idea about the origin. The origin for the question may be 'How memory management in OOPs supporting language impacts the syntax'. (I may be incorrect, if so please correct it)

Under the above origin we can have many related questions.

**If we have the links to various origins**, a low level user can better understand and learn the topics.

Edit-2

May I know the reason behind downvoting my question.

Comment: Please tell why you downvote my question?

Comment: I'm thinking it's not really clear what exactly your feature request is about. For instance, what do you mean by relation/starting links?  Could you [edit] this post and give an example? Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd venture to guess because your post is a bit rambling and doesn't really get to a point.  In any event, votes on Meta aren't criticisms of your post's validity (necessarily), but rather disagreement with your suggestion.

Comment: If you have no idea what to ask, then why are you asking a question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but I *think* the feature you're asking for already exists.

If you click on any tag, you have different tabs that you can use to filter or sort the questions containing that tag. The "frequent" tab sorts the questions with the most links on top.

[image: "frequent" sort on tag page]

To see the most "popular" questions, you can sort by those with the highest votes in that tag.

[image: "votes" sort on tag page]

I'm really not sure what you mean when you say "origin", but the related links are *strongly* related based on their tags.

Lastly, if you're looking for a way to just browse interesting questions but you don't have any question in mind to start with (and then click through the "related" links from that question)...you really are limited to just using the various sorts we already offer, which is quite a few. From the homepage, try "interesting" or "hot" (especially if you've filled in favorite and ignored tags), or from the Questions page, try "active", "frequent", or "votes". If you're looking for things that are generally popular or interesting to the majority of SO users, try Greatest Hits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any way to list questions based on more than one tag? Since tag refers the relation between questions to some extent. I think origin is a group of tags with a meaning.

Comment: There is currently no way to list questions based on more than one tag apart from setting favorite tags (then every question containing those tags will be highlighted on the homepage). I'm not convinced it's a great idea to implement anything more than that; there are so many tag combinations that don't have ANY questions - would you really want to try typing in a set of tags, be told no questions matched, and keep doing that over and over?

Comment: It is just an idea that I had. Yeah we don't get a crisp result every time however I firmly believe that marking questions with tags alone is not sufficient to fit it into some category. It is tough to ask a good question and also it is very tough to organize it in a right manner. :)